# Displaying raw text in HTML like a text editor

Tags: html, unicode, utf-8

I have a UTF8 text string that I would like displayed in a div (or the entire `<body>`) in a web page according to the following rules:

- All characters should be shown literally as they would in a unicode-aware text editor.
- Whitespace should not be ignored.  TABs should indent to some number of spaces (4 or 8 for example).  LFs should cause a line break.
- Text should be automatically word wrapped (as it would for a normal `<p>` paragraph, or as it would in a text editor with word wrap turned on) as the width of the containing div of the text file changes.

Clearly I need to perform some preprocessing steps on the text string before I insert it into the web page (perhaps I need to replace certain characters with named entities `&foo;`.  Perhaps I need to surround the text file with a certain tag, `<pre>` for example, etc).

Precisely what preprocessing steps do I need to perform to achieve the above.  If there are multiple sets of steps that achieve the above, than please answer with the shortest/simplest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(1) and (3) are actually quite simple, if you serve your document as UTF-8 and you're fine with supporting IE >= 8. Then it's:

```
<body style="white-space: pre-wrap">
  (Your String here, '<' and '&' encoded to '&lt;' and '&amp;' respectively)
</body>
```

The [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/white-space) CSS property is the key here.

For (2) you will either need a pre-processing step (a la `s/\t/    /g`) or wait until all browsers support [tab-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-tab-size).

Answer (score 2):

A super-simple way of doing this without any preprocessing is to wrap it in a `<textarea>`.

#### HTML:

```
<textarea readonly class="code">
 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
     <head>
       <meta charset=utf-8 />
       <title>My Code</title>
     </head>
     <body>
       My Content
     </body>
   </html>
</textarea>
```

#### CSS:

```
 .code {
    border:1px solid;
    width:500px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:auto;
    outline:none;
    resize:none;
  }
```

However, this is somewhat un-semantic as the `textarea` is for editing. If you don't care, though, it's a good solution - otherwise, I recommend [Boldewyn's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9811328/719312) answer

http://jsbin.com/oxifek/edit#html,live