# HTML display raw text

Tags: css, html, browser

I have an HTML page where I need to display some log messages. I had them wrapped in `<pre></pre>`, but it seems to be interpreting the log messages as HTML, I want it to print it raw. I tried suggestions given in "[Displaying raw text in HTML like a text editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9811215/displaying-raw-text-in-html-like-a-text-editor)" or "[Prevent automatic line breaks in a <code> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445229/prevent-automatic-line-breaks-in-a-code-tag)" or "[How can I use CSS to preserve line breaks in an HTML <code> block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011641/how-can-i-use-css-to-preserve-line-breaks-in-an-html-code-block)", but none work (they give same result as my original HTML.

Here is my HTML page:

```css
code {
  font-size: 14px;
  display: block;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>pre and code:</h3>
  <pre>
    <code>
[2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#<hashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360">'
    </code>
  </pre>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>only code:</h3>
  <code>
[2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#<hashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360">'
  </code>
</div>

<div>
  <h3>only pre:</h3>
  <pre>
[2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#<hashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360">'
  </pre>
</div>
```

Here is what it renders on browser (latest Chrome in Mac):

```
pre and code:



  [2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#'



only code:


  [2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#'

only pre:

  [2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#'
```

**NOTE the missing `hashie::mash`**

What I want it to print is:

```
  [2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#<hashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360">'
```

I run into similar problems when the log contains some XML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML code in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easiest way I know: use a `<textarea>`

```css
textarea { white-space: nowrap; }
```

```html
<textarea rows="8" cols="50" >
[2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#<hashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360">'
</textarea>
```

Comment: I was unable to make it NOT wrap (tried `wrap="soft"`, `overflow:scroll`). But otherwise the easiest soln indeed.

Comment: I updated the answer to NOT wrap with the css code: `white-space: nowrap;`

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the section you want to display raw in xmp tags.

```
<xmp>[2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#<hashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360">'</xmp>
```

As others have pointed out, xmp is deprecated. This would be better:

```
[2016-06-24 16:06:00]|DEBUG|...., details='#&lthashie::mash worker_address="http://xxx.amazonaws.com:8081" worker_id="0000000008" worker_task_id="776f31e01c530134025722000b27033c:gather_source_file_info_task_1466784360"&gt'
```

Rather than wrapping in xmp tags, you could replace '<' with &lt and replace '>' with &gt

Comment: The `xmp` tag is deprecated and does not work in all browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/xmp

Comment: For the question at hand, I believe this is probably the best answer, deprecated or not, good solution +1

Comment: `<xmp>` element may be officially deprecated, but as of Sep 2019 it's still got "green across the board" for browser support. It was literally intended for showing HTML code as text, so for temporary internal/debugging use (not customer facing), it's the perfect choice.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for my misunderstanding the question. Please replace `<hashie::` with `&#60hashie::`

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing <> (tags) with their html codes. example:

```
<pre>some text</pre> change it to : &lt;pre&gt;sometext &lt;/pre&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

textarea does not take into account the size of the text. Better solution IMO:

```
<pre><code><script style="display:block" type="text/plain">..your raw text here..</script></code></pre>
```

Or with a custom web component:

```
<element-codeblock value="..your raw text here.."></element-codeblock>


<template id="element-codeblock-template">
  <style>
    pre {
      background-color: #f0f0f0;
      padding:  10px;
      border-radius:  5px;
      font-family: monospace;
    }
  </style>
  <pre><code><script style="display:block" type="text/plain">code</script></code></pre>
</template>
<script>
customElements.define('element-codeblock',
  class extends HTMLElement {
    connectedCallback() {
      const template = document.getElementById('element-codeblock-template');
      const templateContent = template.content;
      const node = templateContent.cloneNode(true);
      const scriptTag = node.querySelector('script[type="text/plain"]');
      scriptTag.textContent = this.getAttribute('value');
      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' }).appendChild(node);
    }
  }
);
</script>
```